# Destructing deeply nested enum, do I have to type each item?

Tags: typescript, enums, destructuring

I have a deeply nested object, which is running into an error since all enum are not present in object.

In the example, the destructured `const { position, func }` are both of type `any`. When I inspect indexes[table][index], I can see the proper types of all 3 (indexes, table and index)

```
enum Index {
    BY_DEFAULT = "bydefault",
    BY_ID = "byid",
}
enum Table {
    DELIVERY = 'delivery',
}
const indexes = {
    [Table.DELIVERY]: {
        [Index.BY_DEFAULT]: { position: 1, func: (data: { index: number }) => data.index + 5 },
    }
};
const get = async (data: any, table: Table, index: Index) => {
    const { position, func } = indexes[table][index]
    func(data)
}
get({ index: 1 }, Table.DELIVERY, Index.BY_DEFAULT)
```

Typescript 3.7.3

The error here is because BY_ID is not in the nested object, I am not sure what the proper way to refactor this code would be. Any help appreciated

Comment: Strange it shows appropriate types here in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAkiAmwAeUDeAoKWoCECaA+gCICiAYgIICqAMgCpQC8UARAEYCeiAZgIZgAbAC4sANOgC+6UJCh1ebAcDSZspGjABqJAEp4mUAOSIBASwBuwAE4dD4qegDGAexABnIVFMJkwNwYxsKABteUVgADp1LV08AF0ALhUgoOC4RCQI-GJyanpEtCgAB2c3UyFTVySARlEobjAQRySACnheIV4k1C8fJCTwCDZrKAkASiYAPih2zojvDKgAaigAVlHxIKkJAG50J1cPKABzYE9mXjcOJqg2jq6oXhAOOs7wpLClOoXkJPTkCaMaaBbAudyeHolMoVVx1Bo3CQGH5IPzBN5KOLBZFxVRYeGOO6dMaSfanIQtHrImobOQKJRREgabR6Or-TLZUiUWh0MZAA) (typescript 3.7.2)

Comment: @AlekseyL. the playground gives better errors than VSCode. Here is an updated example [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=52#code/KYOwrgtgBAkiAmwAeUDeAoKWoCECaA+gCICiAYgIICqAMgCpQC8UARAEYCeiAZgIZgAbAC4sANJmz4CMIk1acAlvDHoAvulCQodXmwHA0ErKRowAaiQBKeOQHJEAhQDdgAJw63x6gMYB7EADOQlAKCMjAAXIY2FAA2jp6wAB0JuZWeAC6AFyGMTGxcIhISVKklLR02WhQAA6+AQpCCv45AIyiUNxgIN45ABTwvEK8OaghYUg54BBsblCqAJRMAHxQg8NJoUVQANRQAKzz4jHqqgDc6H6BwQDmwMHMvAEcPVADQyNQvCAcHcOJOQS+g6W2QOUKyCWjFW0WwVyC1TqDSa-g6XVeqjkoKQEVi-30GVi2IyRk63W872GCzU6DuQj6Y2xbSO2l0+hSJFMFmsHQhxVK5Go9AWQA)

Comment: OK, so what's the question now ? The error in playground is because `Index.BY_ID` is not in the map

Answer (score 0):

A `type` needs to be created for the indexed value. In the example below I defined a `type` for it and casted the value of `[Index.BY_DEFAULT]` to the created type.

```
enum Index {
    BY_DEFAULT = "bydefault",
}
enum Table {
    DELIVERY = 'delivery',
}

type IndexedValueType = { position: number, func: (data: { index: number }) => number }

const indexes = {
    [Table.DELIVERY]: {
        [Index.BY_DEFAULT]: <IndexedValueType>{ position: 1, func: (data: { index: number }) => data.index + 5 },
    }
}

const get = async (data: any, table: Table, index: Index) => {
    const { position, func } = indexes[table][index]
    func(data)
}

get({ index: 1 }, Table.DELIVERY, Index.BY_DEFAULT)
```